# How to prompt for restart based on uptime?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a powershell script that will prompt the user to restart their computer based on their uptime. Preferably I want it to prompt on day 5 and force a restart on day 7.

This script

```
(get-date)-([System.Management.ManagementDateTimeconverter]::ToDateTime((Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem).lastbootuptime))|select days
```

Gives me the uptime days and if it returns an amount greater than 5 I want it to run

```
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Shutdown | Restart"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,300) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$objForm.FormBorderStyle = "FixedSingle"

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
{$objForm.Close()}})

$SButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$SButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,220)
$SButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)
$SButton.Text = "Shutdown"
$SButton.Add_Click({Stop-Computer -Force})
$objForm.Controls.Add($SButton)

$RButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$RButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(110,220)
$RButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)
$RButton.Text = "Restart"
$RButton.Add_Click({Restart-Computer -Force})
$objForm.Controls.Add($RButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(205,220)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$outlook = @(Get-Process | ?{ $_.Name -eq "outlook" }).Count
$word = @(Get-Process | ?{ $_.Name -eq "winword" }).Count

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,120)
$objLabel.Text = "Please ensure you have saved your work before proceeding.`n`nYou currently have $outlook Outlook and $word Word windows open."
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
```

And if possible I want it to force the restart if it's greater than 7

Comment: is there some reason you don't simply wrap that in an `if` test?

Comment: here's a slightly faster method to get the uptime in days. it also counts from midnite of each day by ignoring the time component. >>> `((Get-Date).Date - (Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem).LastBootupTime.Date).Days` <<<